# MITIE library for NLP

Tags: python, neural-network, nlp, rasa-nlu

I am trying to understand how MITIE is integrated with Rasa. I wanted to know what exactly the MITIE file total_word_feature_extractor.dat contain? I dont find any good documentation about this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you poke around deep enough in the [MITIE repo](https://github.com/mit-nlp/MITIE)'s on Github you can find your answer. For example here is a [bit of information](https://github.com/mit-nlp/MITIE/issues/31#issuecomment-168979001) about what goes into that file.

> As for what's inside, yes, it's a variant of word2vec based on the two step CCA method from this paper: http://icml.cc/2012/papers/763.pdf. I also upgraded it to include something that is similar to the CCA method but works on out of sample words by analyzing their morphology to produce a word vector. This significantly improved the results on datasets containing lots of words not in the original dictionary.

As far as how MITIE integrates into Rasa, it is one of a [few backend choices](http://rasa-nlu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#first-alternative-mitie) for Rasa. It provides a [few pipeline components](http://rasa-nlu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pipeline.html#pre-configured-pipelines) that can do both intent classification and NER. Both of which use an SVM and use the `total_word_feature_extractor.dat` to provide the individual word vectors.